# Initialising timer interrupt crashes Mega 2560

Tags: interrupt, timers, arduino-setup

Below is the entirety of my prototype code, the cycling of pin 13 is what I use to confirm the board is restarting. The board resets continually on this implementation of initialising the interrupt. There is no code implemented for the interrupt, simply initialising the interrupt and specifically enabling the Output Compare Interrupt by setting its bit high is enough to cause the crash. The evidence of the crash is the onboard LED cycling as instructed in the `setup()` routine.

I have tried setting `OCR3A` in one and two operations, I have tried initialising `TIMSK3` and not, I have tried intialising `TCNT3` to zero and non-zero values, and setting the prescaler with the bit shift and the discrete value, nothing seems to work..

What is going on?

```
void FlashLED() {
  digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13));
  delay(100);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  FlashLED();
  
  // Initialise timer 3 and interrupt
  noInterrupts();
  TCCR3A = 0;
  TCCR3B = 0;
  TIMSK3 = 0;
  TCNT3 = 0;

  // Initialise OCR3A in two operations, as OCR3A = 62500; Serial.print(OCR3A); yields 36 (low byte only)
  unsigned int count = 62500;
  OCR3AH = count >> 8;
  OCR3AL = count;
  TCCR3B |= 1 << WGM32; // CTC Mode
  //TCCR3B |= 4; // Prescaler 256
  TCCR3B |= 1 << CS32; // Prescaler 256
  
  TIMSK3 |= 1 << OCIE3A; // Output Compare Interrupt Enable
  interrupts();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

**Update:**

I had also been trying with an empty ISR handler and discounted its effect:

```
ISR(Timer3_COMPA_vect) {

}
```

However, as the astute viewer would notice, the signature is incorrect in its capitalisation. The correct handler is

```
ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect) {

}
```

This has resolved the issue.

Comment: You have enabled the timer and also its interrupts but you have no interrupt handler.  The interrupt has to go somewhere and as it is it's going who-knows-where.  Add an ISR and I believe that will resolve your issue.

Comment: How irritating. I have for hours been working with an empty ISR handler, the whole problem has been incorrect capitalisation!! The Oscar Liang tutorial routinely mixes the case of the ISR, so it never occurred to me to change it: https://oscarliang.com/arduino-timer-and-interrupt-tutorial/ Feel free to submit ans answer that I will accept, since your prompt got me home.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: Unrelated; You should be able to use `OCR3A = count` to set both the H and L register with only one line of code.

Comment: That is what I was doing initially, but using Serial.print(OCR3A); returned 36, indicating that only the low byte was being written. I don't know how my code could possibly be behaving differently to anyone else's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled the timer and also its interrupts but you have no interrupt handler. The interrupt has to go somewhere and as it is it's going who-knows-where. Add an ISR and I believe that will resolve your issue.

Yes, the capitalization is important!